# anyway to see method execution times in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to debug a certain ViewController I have and I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what is causing my lag time for the view to show.

IS there any debugger tool in Xcode that will show me how long my methods are taking to run so i can at least find the right place to start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instruments has a profiler built into it ever since iOS 4.0 (before which you used a stand-alone profiler tool called Shark).

Here's a quick little tutorial that will get you started: http://blancer.com/tutorials/flex/78335/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in/

If you don't know about Instruments, you should. It's how you know what's really going on inside your code while it runs.

Comment: LOL, I have been using the leaks tool for months and never saw the timer! Thanks!

Comment: [www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) provides some practical examples that help work with Time Profiler and Alloc/Leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Time Profiler as suggested by Dan you can also use Sampler instrument which generally stops a program at prescribed intervals and records the stack trace information for each of the program’s threads. You can use this information to determine where execution time is being spent in your program and improve your code to reduce running time.

The main difference between sampler & Time profiler :

Sampler instrument operates upon a single process but Time Profiler operates upon a single/All processes.